# Laggy animation on Firefox

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, filter, mask

I've replicated [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=SeLOt_BRAqc#t=936) effect using `mask` and `filter`.

This is what I've done:

- Applied two `mask`s on two different `text` elements, one on the left for the blurred text and one on the right for the normal text.
- Animated both `mask`s and the `ellipse` to get the final effect.

Everything works fine, however the animation is lagging on Firefox. Is there any way to make the animation smooth?

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/vEmOPL)**

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #300 10%, #000 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #300 10%, #000 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #300 10%, #000 100%);
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="200" viewBox="0 0 700 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask-left" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="200">
      <path id="d1" d="M0,30 h0 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h0z" fill="white" />
      <animate xlink:href="#d1" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M0,30 h0 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h-0z" to="M0,30 h700 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h-700z" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask-right" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="200">
      <path id="d2" d="M700,30 h-672 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h672z" fill="white" />
      <animate xlink:href="#d2" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M700,30 h-700 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h700z" to="M700,30 h0 c-35,15 -35,125 0,140 h0z" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text mask="url(#mask-right)" x="350" y="120" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" font-size="50" font-family="Ubuntu">Magic of Filter and Masking</text>
  <text mask="url(#mask-left)" filter="url(#blur)" x="350" y="120" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" font-size="50" font-family="Ubuntu">Magic of Filter and Masking</text>
  <ellipse id="e" cx="26" cy="100" rx="25" ry="70" fill="none" stroke="#600" stroke-width="2" />
  <animate xlink:href="#e" attributeType="XML" attributeName="cx" from="0" to="700" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm no expert in `SVG` but what I can tell you is that if you use your [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/vEmOPL) it reallly lags on Firefox but if you use the code that you are using on your SO snippet it runs smoothly, see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbEpLB), just by editing the `SVG`

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at your svg animation in different browsers.
But it works without any lagging in FireFox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer it's not working at all.

Maybe make use of [Fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html), this is supported for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks! I do know about [Fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html),  however this still does not answer my question.